# Percona xtradb cluster with asynch slaves

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, percona

I have a Percona xtradb cluster set up with 3 nodes. Node 1 is also set up as a master with an asynchronous slave. When I make an update to Node 1, it is replicated to the cluster as well as the slave. However, when I make an update to Node 2 or Node 3 the slave does not replicate Node 1.

When an update is made on node 2 or node 3, node1 doesn't update his bin-log.

How can I get the bin logs to stay up to date?

And if all three nodes were masters to asynch slaves how can I keep all 3 bin-logs the same?

Comment: Did you enable log-slave-updates on node1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the binlog entries in the log of node1 for node2 and node3 by adding the log-slave-updates setting on node1.

But the binlogs will not be consistant across the nodes so you can't fail the async slave to node2 and node 3 without rebuilding the slave.